# How to create a tar.gz file from a list of files?

Tags: java, compression

I have a List files of file paths that I want to create a tar.gz from these files.  Can someone help me?  Thanks.

Comment: from which environment, Linux or windows ?

Comment: @user270811 try [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/642457/java/java/Create-tar-gz)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script and invoke this script using `ProcessBuilder`

`compressUtil.sh`

```
tar -cf <tar_name> <list_of_files_space_seperated>
gzip <tar_name>
```

`OSX` is Unix Like, you can check whether it is same as `Ubuntu`

or execute the commands to create `tar` and `gunzip` one by one using `ProcessBuilder`